# What algorithm could be used to fast clustering point in polyline shape?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

Suppose we have a line consisting of 2dpoints like this
[image]

What algorithm could most efficiently compute clusters in that line given the input of active points?

Red here is all points.
Yellow - active points in given time.

In this example algorithm should find two clusters (BLUE).

Comment: remove non-active points, use a regular clustering algorithm.

Comment: It would be O(n^2) where n is number of active points, right? Because I would need to compute distance for every pair of points.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Cluster the points by their index. This can be done in linear time. Save a cluster's bounding box in this process
2. For each pair of clusters

   - Check if the bounding boxes intersect or have a maximum distance t
   - If so, check if there are two points from both clusters that have a maximum distance of t
   - If so, merge the clusters

t is a distance threshold. It can be either static or based on the cluster (e.g. the maximum distance to the nearest neighbour of any cluster's point).

This algorithm has still quadratic time complexity, but it should be fast enough due to pre-clustering and bounding box test.